Problem for finding a set of prime numbers with a specific condition
I want to find all nonempty sets $X$ consisting of some primes, which satisfies the condition below:
For any finite subset of $X$, says $Y=\{p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k\}$, all prime divisors of $p_1p_2\dots p_k+1$ belongs to $X$.
Here are my results. I know that $2$ must be in $X$, since any odd prime $p$ ocurring in $X$ leads to $p+1$ having $2$ as a divisor. Hence $3$ must be in $X$, and so is $7,5,11,23\dots$
$X$ can be the whole prime numbers. But could $X$ be a proper subset of all primes?

If I understand it well, $X$ has to be infinite, because otherwise you could pick $Y=X$.

2×3+1=7, 3×7+1=2×11, 2×7+1=3×5, etc.
@Dietrich Burde
And sorry for my notation $p_i$.

Why do you only multiply two primes plus one? It says $p_1p_2\cdots p_k+1$?

But the product of $Y$ +1 may only have prime divisors in $X$.
@Matthew Spam

@Dietrich Burde
You can regard "$Y={p_1,p_2,\dots, p_k}$" as "$Y={x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k}$".

@ChaosInferno if $Y=X$, then the product of $Y$ plus 1 cannot be divisible by any of the primes of $X$, since all of these primes divide the product of $Y$ (it is basically just Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes).

See also Euclid-Mullin sequence and the generalization discussed here: arXiv:1605.08929 [math.NT].

Yes, you  are right.
@Matthew Spam

@Eric Towers Thanks. Although this is a little different from the problem, but helps.
